# Whats wrong with this method? Why won't it pass test case?

Tags: java, methods, testcase

This code is supposed to count from an inputted parameter from a user, pass it to a function and it counts it down to one. I *believe* the program acts as it should, the problem is that it doesn't pass Mooc.fi's tests

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
         
    printFromNumbertoOne(number);

}
public static void printFromNumbertoOne(int number) {
    for (int i = number; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

The error I'm receiving is:
Method printFromNumberToOne(int) of class FromParameterToOne missing

What am I missing? And is there a way to check the test cases? Mooc.fi seems like it's very picky on what it takes for answers.

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the capital T in the name of `printFromNumbertoOne`

Answer (score 0):

CAMELCASE of the method!

After beating my head against this problem all day it came to me after taking a break.

It should be printFromNumberToOne